# differ sessions in different browser-tabs

Tags: browser, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

Hi, I developed multi language and multi currency web application so I store current language and currency in session.But when customer open in different tabs when customer change language and currency it effect other tabs language and currency because i used currency and language via session
     I wanted to use query string but my customer does not want query string
what should I do?how can i initialize different session in different tabs?
     or can I access other tabs and close them in JS or .NET ?

Comment: Your server does not see the tabs, no way to consider that fact. From the servers point of view that is _one_ browser. Don't try to outsmart your users, you will fail. If they want to use tabs, then have them.

Comment: @arkascha if they use different tabs the product price will wrong... product value 100 if currency EUR it will 100 euro in other tab if user choose dolar it will be 100 dolars

Comment: If the user chooses to select different currencies whist working inside a single browser, then that is his choice. Switching the currency should take immediate effect to _all_ tabs. THe issue here is that apparently your implementation jumps t  short here: you keep currency and amount separate which clearly must not be the case, since they only make sense together.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the customer to use different browsers. This may help. I am not sure if it can be done otherwise.

Comment: this is not ERP...customer all web user from world

Answer (score 0):

instead of querystring you can use cookies or localstorage (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage)

Comment: cookie or localstora it is same

Comment: nope, it is different things. to compare, it is like - cars and bicycles are the same, because they both have wheels :)